# Redirect shopify app url to custom url

Tags: shopify

I have created an app in shopify and after installing it in the store, I want when I click on the app then it will redirect to other domain like www.abc.com instead of open it in the shopify admin.

I have checked this type of functionality in many apps but don't know how to implement it. Please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you need to create account as Shopify partners. Once you sign-in in your account, you will see [Apps](https://app.shopify.com/services/partners/api_clients/new) on the left side of the dashboard. You will see **Redirection URL** in the options available. You can also give name and other details of your app in this session.

Answer (score 0):

most likely your app is an embedded app that is why it is not opening new tab upon clicking from admin app listing. you first understand whether your app required embedding functionality or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Go to **App setup** -> **App url** and provide you link. Than find below param **Embedded app** -> **manage** and disable embedded option.